# Psychic Game event key - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {

        //ctrl+r to refresh page, but also to set lettersGuessed by player to ''.
        //the 'r' was being recorded as a guess.
        if (event.keyCode == 73 && event.ctrlKey) {
            startGame();
        }

        //allows only A-Z on keyboard to be registered as answers
        else if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {

            var key = event.key;
            console.log(computerChoice);
            if (guesses != 0) {
                    lettersGuessed += key + ', ';
                    if (key == computerChoice) {
                        wins++;
                        display.innerHTML = "You WIN! The computer chose " + computerChoice +
                                            "<br/> To play again press any button.";
                        startGame();
                    }
                    else if (key != computerChoice && guesses != 0) {
                        guesses--;
                        displayResults('Keep Guessing!', key, 'Not Telling!' , guesses);
                    }
                }
                else if (guesses == 0) {
                    losses++;
                    display.innerHTML = "You LOSE! The computer chose: " + computerChoice +
                                        "<br/> To play again press any button.";
                    startGame();
                }
            }

        //this runs when ctrl+r is hit. shouldn't this not run? for some reason its reading the ctrl part
        //when I press ctrl+r.
        else {
            alert("Only A-Z allowed.");
        }
    }
```

This function is the main code that runs my psychic game. The player has 10 lives to guess a random letter. In the if statement I set the key codes for ctrl+r to set the players lettersGuessed = '', I know this is also to refresh the page and I don't mind. I had to do this because my else if statement was recording the 'r' as a guess from the user. However, now the ctrl when pressed activates my else statement at the bottom to alert "Only A-Z allowed."

Shouldn't the else statement at the bottom not run because of my initial if statement? I'm giving ctrl+r something to do before the alert goes off.

What I'm trying to do is to not have the alert go off specifically when ctrl+r is hit.

Comment: Hey Jeff, welcome to StackOverflow. It's great that you posted a question for us to answer. We're happy to help. However, to do so you need to help us help you. As your question currently stands it's not very informative. You've given us a wall of code and a few lines of explanation describing your problem. That's not sufficient. Please take the time to explain what your code does, where it fails and what you'd like it to do in more detail so that we'll be in a better position to help you. Thank you and hope you have a wonderful experience on StackOverflow. Meanwhile, I'll post an answer ASAP.

Comment: Hi Aadit, added some comments in my code and more info about the problem. Hope this clarifies some things. :)

Answer (score 0):

pressing `ctrl + r` defaults for page reload in browsers. for sanity check, try any other `keyCode` like `i`.

also i would recommend to use `event.which` as a fallback option :

```
 event.keyCode || event.which == 73 && event.ctrlKey
```